# Statistical Analysis of antibiograms

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, logistic-regression

I'm currently working on a dataset obtained from different antibiograms tests of different people. My aim is to propose a model to predict and study sensibility/resistance of atibiotics. I'll attach an example of the dataframe  for more visual information but to resume I have 900 patients with 210 columns of antibiotics (2 columns for each antibiotic, 1 for senstivity, 1 for CMI).

I want to propose a logistic regression since we have many categorical variables (M/F, Sensible/not sensible/slightly sensible...etc). I end up stuck in how to give form to this regression, as my data are quite poor on biological variables.

I have many antibiotics but just 2 biological variables so I'm a bit confused in the sense that I don't really know if I can extract useful information trying to model antibiotic resistance as function of these biological variables and the CMI (Minimum inhibitory concentration). Or change the whole way of thinking to extract information.
[image: Antibiogram header]

Comment: Hey! Please read the how-to ask and adhere to the guides found there. Currently, you do not supply a reproducible example, because you posted your data as an image and because you did not include what you have tried so far to solve your issue (code). If your question is more aimed at the theory and less so the practical programming, you can copy paste your question into crossvalidated

Comment: Interesting problem, but off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understood your purpose, based on my knowledge you must first import the *pandas* library and read your data into a pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("antibiograms.csv")
```

Then explore and clean your data. You can use the **df.head**, **df.info**,
and **df.isnull** methods (the last one is so important and I frequently use) to get a summary of your data, check the data types, the descriptive statistics, and the missing values. You can also use the **df.drop** and **df.fillna** methods to remove or fill unwanted or missing values.

After that transform the categorical variables into numerical variables. You can use the **pd.get_dummies** function to create dummy variables for each category of a variable. (For example, if you have a variable called "Gender" with two categories "M" and "F", you can create two dummy variables called "Gender_M" and "Gender_F" that take the value 1 or 0 depending on the gender)
Then split your data into training and test sets. You can use the train_test_split function from the **sklearn** library to randomly split your data into a training set and a test set.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = df.drop("Outcome", axis=1) # the features
y = df["Outcome"] # the target variable
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, 
random_state=42)
```

After that you must fit the logistic regression model with **LogisticRegression** *class*.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression(penalty="l2", solver="lbfgs")
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Finally make predictions with the logistic regression model:

```
y_pred = lr.predict(X_test) # the predicted class labels
y_prob = lr.predict_proba(X_test) # the predicted probabilities
```

Last but not least, You can use various metrics and methods to measure how well your model performs on the test set.